# No Internet through Messenger/Whatsapp/Viber apps

Tags: samsung, connection-issues, internet

I have a Samsung note 5
I have Internet through a web browser but no Internet through Messenger, Whatsapp and Viber apps.
Do you have any advice why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: Hi Ron, can you please let us know what you've done to trouble shoot and the following details: OS inc version, other apps that do or don't have internet.

Answer (score 0):

This could have happened if you're using a WiFi  network which uses a proxy server. The browser works just fine in this case but the other apps like WhatsApp or Messenger are blocked through the settings of the proxy server. TRY running these applications using your own mobile data or a WiFi network which do not have proxy.